# How to move a physical body to a specific point

Tags: physics, coronasdk

I am totally new to Corona, and I want to know that how to move a physical body to a specific point?

Answer (score 0):

Here I derived formula for moving a physical body to a specific point

```
local force = 0.05    --Speed of body

local current_Position_X = myBody.x    --myBody is a physical body which has to move
local current_Position_Y = myBody.y

local N_Movement_X = target.x - current_Position_X    --target point where my body has to move
local N_Movement_Y = target.y - current_Position_Y

local N_Distance_X = N_Movement_X * N_Movement_X
local N_Distance_Y = N_Movement_Y * N_Movement_Y

local distance = math.sqrt(N_Distance_X + N_Distance_Y)
local unit = 1/distance

N_Movement_X = N_Distance_X * unit    --Normalizing distance
N_Movement_Y = N_Distance_Y * unit    --Normalizing distance

local forceX = distance * N_Movement_X
local forceY = distance * N_Movement_Y

myBody:setLinearVelocity(forceX*force, forceY* force)
```